# search for questions on quadratic polynomial in two variables and a matrix determinant

Tags: support

From time to time, someone posts a question amounting to setting
$$ g(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f  $$
to zero. Then either the OP or someone answering points out the significance of the determinant of
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2a & b & d \\
b & 2c & e \\
d & e & 2f
\end{array}
\right),   
$$ which is double
$$ 4acf+edb -ae^2-cd^2-fb^2. $$

Oh, this determinant, along with the $\pm$ sign of $b^2 - 4 a c,$ tells us whether we have degenerate, empty, nondegenerate, hyperbola, ellipse, etc.

I have been trying the trick with using Google with expressions involving exponents and putting suffix     site:math.stackexchange.com   SEE http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/find-a-specific-question-on-main

but no luck so far. Part of the trouble is my lack of internet savvy, part is the separation of the different parts of the observation among th original question, the comments, and the answer(s).

Anyway, this has been posted multiple times over the years, if anyone can find one or more examples that would be very nice.

In case it helps, this has to do with the extra material I am putting at the end of my answer [What's so special about the form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128125/whats-so-special-about-the-form-ax22bxycy2/1128194#1128194)

with an application one day later at [$x^2+y^2+9=3(x+y)+xy$ Find all pairs of real $x,y$ that meet this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129124/x2y29-3xyxy-find-all-pairs-of-real-x-y-that-meet-this-equation/1129395#1129395)

Comment: Some possibilities: [Determine if a conic is degenerate with the determinant.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387177), [How to determine if arbitrary point lies inside or outside a conic](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/817130), [transformation of conic section](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008919), [Conic Sections with Matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/585215)

Comment: @Fundamental, thank you, the second and third look just right.